# How to Delete Hybrid Connections

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-hybrid-connections, azure-relay

I accidentally deleted the relay without deleting the hybrid connection first.  It appears like this left an orphaned hybrid connection, as whenever I try to create a new hybrid connection I get this error:

Failed to add hybrid connection xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:
A hybrid connection already exists with Hostname xxxxx and Port xxxx, which must remain unique on the App Service Plan.

I've searched everywhere trying to find the hybrid connection and I can't see it.  I'd appreciate any help on this.

Cross posted on MSDN: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/becb2be7-25e2-4992-a64c-cd784094d0bb/how-to-delete-hybrid-connections?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows

Thanks.

Comment: How did you delete the Relay namespace? Are you trying to recreate the Hybrid Connection under a different namespace?

Comment: What happens when you try to access the resource url? (e.g. https://YOUR_RELAY_NAMESPCE.servicebus.windows.net/YOUR_HYBRID_CONNECTION)

Comment: If you click on the Relay you have the ability to delete it.  I just hit the delete button.

Comment: When I go to the resource URL I get a "This site can’t be reached", but that's because the Relay has been deleted.

Comment: I found it the easiest to remove the app (webapp or azure function) and that removes the hybrid connections. You can also try and call this API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/relay/hybrid-connections/delete?tabs=HTTP

Answer (score 0):

We will need to go to the networking tab on this webapp, and find and remove the Hybrid Connection from it. While we did delete this relay, the app still has a reference to it and that needs to be removed first.

Could you please try this and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: There is no hybrid connection associated with the Web App.

Comment: Could you please navigate to resources.azure.com and expand the subscription --> resource group --> search for the Hybrid Connection. If you can see the Hybrid connection, can you just try deleting it?

Comment: Have you tried this already?  It doesn't look like Hybrid Connections appear here, only the relays.